# Unexpected Selenium behaviour after selecting from dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a Selenium script in VBA to select from a dropdown then press the `Done` button.

By default the page shows `Bangladesh` in it's landing page. I need to change it to `Canada`.

My script selects the desired country from the dropdown but when it is supposed to click the `Done` button, it clicks elsewhere so the country remains unchanged. The script doesn't show any error.

[Site link:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071V5DQ56)

```
Sub SelectDropdown()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

    With driver
        .get "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071V5DQ56/"
        .FindElementByCss("#nav-packard-glow-loc-icon", timeout:=5000).Click
        .FindElementByCss("#GLUXCountryListDropdown", timeout:=5000).Click
        .FindElementById("GLUXCountryList", timeout:=5000).AsSelect.SelectByText "Canada"
        .FindElementByCss("div.a-popover-wrapper button[name='glowDoneButton']", timeout:=5000).Click
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```

This is what it shows in the landing page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it needs a little breather before the final click.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SelectDropdown()
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
    With driver
        .get "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071V5DQ56/"
        .FindElementByCss("#nav-packard-glow-loc-icon", timeout:=5000).Click
        .FindElementByCss("#GLUXCountryListDropdown", timeout:=5000).Click
        .FindElementById("GLUXCountryList", timeout:=5000).AsSelect.SelectByText "Canada"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        .FindElementByCss("[data-action='a-popover-close']", timeout:=5000).Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @QHarr, thanks for your solution. My question perhaps misguided you. My script can successfully select the Country `Canada` from the dropdown. What it can't do is press the `Done` button to reflect the change to that page. Once again - It's all about prssing the `Done` button. Btw, I tried your script but still the same as I was having earlier.

Comment: No damn way!!! Yep, you made it @QHarr. Do you know whether there is any option for ***`Focus`*** in vba selenium binding?

Comment: Usually use  moveToElement()